# Codeigniter error log not working

Tags: codeigniter, logging, codeigniter-2

I want to log my details for log my application event. So i have changed config.php as follows.

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
$config['log_path'] = 'application/logs/main';
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
```

I use it in my controller as like this.

```
log_message('error', 'Some variable did not contain a value.');
```

I grant write permission to main file. bt it is not working. What is the issue.

Comment: The log path should have a trailing slash, can it be that simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log_path is meant to be a folder not a file. If main is a folder then you should add a trailing /